# Relative version of Browder's theorem on H-spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

A theorem of W. Browder [1]  from 1961 says that an H-space $X$ with finitely generated integral homology (meaning that $H_*(X)$ is finitely generated) has $\pi_2(X) = 0$. This generalizes Cartan's famous theorem that $\pi_2$ of a Lie group vanishes.

I would like to know if there is a relative version of the following sort: Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is an H-space map and $\ker(H_*(X) \to H_*(Y))$ is finitely generated. Then can I conclude that $\ker(\pi_2(X) \to \pi_2(Y))$ is $0$?

[1] Torsion in H-Spaces, Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 74, No. 1 (Jul., 1961), pp. 24-51. http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970305 .

Comment: $X=K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ is a counterexample to your first paragraph. Did you forget an assumption?

Comment: @archipelago: "finitely generated" refers to the totality of the integral homology groups.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @archipelago Sorry for the confusion; I've edited to clarify "finitely generated".

Comment: Do you have an example of an H-space map with finitely generated (non-trivial) kernel on homology, which doesn't just have $H_*(X)$ finitely generated? Feels weird to me, shouldn't there be some Hopf algebra magic that makes this impossible?

Comment: @AchimKrause Good question; I don't know an example. I'm far from an expert on this so I was hoping that someone would tell me how to find that `magic'.

Comment: @DannyRuberman you also want to assume in the second paragraph of your post that $H_*(X)$ and $H_*(Y)$ are both finitely generated. Right?

Comment: @JohnKlein I don't think so. Since I'm easily confused by logic, let me state it in the contrapositive setting in which the question arises. I have two H-spaces X and Y (actually groups) and a map, and I know that the kernel on $\pi_2$ is non-zero. So I know that $H_*(X)$ is infinitely generated, but I'd like to know that the kernel is infinitely generated.

Comment: @DannyRuberman If $X$ and $Y$ are topological groups and $f$ is a homomorphism. Then the homotopy fiber $F$ of $f$ at the identity element of $Y$ has the homotopy type of a topological group.  If you knew that $H_\ast(F)$ is totally finitely generated then it follows that $F$ has the homotopy type of a homotopy finite space. In particular, $F$ is a homotopy finite $H$-space, so $\pi_2(F) = 0$.

However, you are assuming less than I am: you are assuming that the kernel of $H_*(f)$ is totally finitely generated. Can you get away with my stricter assumption?

Comment: @JohnKlein I'm not sure that I know how to get the stronger assumption. I'd be glad to continue the conversation off-line and tell you more than makes sense to try to put in the comments. I think you might know where to find me...